# Programmatically pin a tab in Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I made [a small Chrome extension](http://ericviala.github.io/Skwares/) that opens a new tab and displays your bookmarks in it.

I'd like this new tab to be automatically pinned. The code is like so :

```
chrome.tabs.create({
                    "url": chrome.extension.getURL("skwares.html")
                },
                function(tab) {
                    tab.highlighted = true;
                    tab.active = true;
                    tab.pinned = true;
                });
```

The new tab opens alright, but is not pinned. What did I miss?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just need to move the pinned option into the create properties, rather than the callback:

```
chrome.tabs.create({
  url: "skwares.html",
  pinned: true
}, function(tab) {
  console.log('created', tab);
});
```

Also, by default ['active' is set to true](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-create) when you create a new tab so you shouldn't need to set it again.