# Is there is a way to make the tab size on browser smaller?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

so I have a little chrome extension that I am building for fun that opens up some tabs on chrome
but I want to change the tab width to be like this but I cant find how to change the tab size using js
[small tab width](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KIfwM.png)

Answer (score 0):

That's a pinned tab (pinned tabs only show the icon), see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36289244/programmatically-pin-a-tab-in-google-chrome) (tldr: `"pinned": true` in `tabs.create()` options) for how to pin a tab when creating it